# how to sort out by desc mysql price with commas

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mprice where price BETWEEN '1,000' AND '3,250' ORDER BY CAST( 
REPLACE(price,',', '.') AS decimal(10,2)) LIMIT $from, $max_results"
```

This query is showing result like this

```
1,000
2,000
3,250
10,900
11,700
27,600
```

and I want like this

```
1,000
2,000
3,250
 only
```

How can I do this? Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like the `$max_results` variable doesn't contain what you think it contains.

Comment: max results is showing maximum result example :$max_results = 100;

Comment: @user3162123: This question serves as an example of why we don't store "price" or "amount" or any numeric values in VARCHAR columns.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat bizarre functionality. I would recommend revisiting your schema design, if you have an option to do so, and utilizing a numeric type for your price column (you can include localization information in another column). That said, you *can* get it to work using the following query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    mprice
WHERE
    CAST(REPLACE(price, ',', '.') AS decimal(10,2)) BETWEEN 1.00 AND 3.25
ORDER BY
    CAST(REPLACE(price, ',', '.') AS decimal(10,2))
```

Note that in your code you were attempting to restrict `price` to values between  `'1,000'` and `'3,250'`. However, string comparison doesn't work well with numeric types, as it sorts lexicographically (alphabetically), treating numbers just like any other character. In this case, it was including values such as `10,900` and `27,600` because the first digit of these strings was between `1` and `3`, which are the first characters of `'1,000'` and `'3,250'`.

When you cast the prices to numbers, you can correct this behavior. However, you also need to convert your filtering values to numbers, in this case `1.00` and `3.25`.

Comment: (Not directed to you Brett) - It's poor practice to use `SELECT *` @user3162123 as any future additional columns to your table will be included but may not necessarily be needed in this query thus expending your resources.

Comment: Agreed. Listen to J Young, his comment is valid.

Comment: The predicate in the WHERE clause is not sargable; that is, MySQL cannot make use of an index range scan operation to satisfy the predicate; MySQL has to evaluate the expression for every flipping row in the table.